# How to get html source of youtube video with http and not https

Tags: c#, html, ssl, curl, youtube

I am trying to get the html source of a youtube video using cURL command line but I need it to be without https/ssl. 
My problem is that I must use the compiled version of cURL with SSL/SSH.

I am using the following command:

```
curl --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36" -L -x http://my.foo.proxy:8080 http://youtube.com/watch?v=youtubevideo > html.html
```

this works but a specific part of the html source is in https (look for a really long script string inside that file. some of the links there start with httpS)

```
curl --proto =http --proto-redir =http --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36" -L -x http://my.foo.proxy:8080 http://youtube.com/watch?v=youtubevideo > html.html
```

this command causes an error:

> protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl.

which is really weird because the curl version I am using does have ssl and I dont even want https (see the -proto and -proto-redir args).

As a test I also tried using .NET Webclient class like:

```
public static void DownloadString (string address)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient ();
        string reply = client.DownloadString (address);

        Console.WriteLine (reply);
    }
```

and in this case I get a html source file without https.

My question is, how do I get a html source file of a youtube video using cURL without https inside my html source file like when I use .NET/Webclient?

Comment: Does your error get thrown when you download the source or when you're  parsing it?

Comment: when I hit enter. Inside cmd I see 2 lines of progress (download speed, etc.) but it is empty. A html.html file is created on my drive but it is also empty. Looks like it is trying to connect and then terminates because of whatever reason. I doubt it is because of https as stated.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have some more lerking around to do. It might even turn out to be another question in the end.

Answer (score 0):

using an user agent without firefox fixes this issue when used inside a console:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101
```

When used with a binding set SSL_VERIFYPEER to false and SSL_VERIFYHOST to 0. Allows man in the middle attack but if that is the only option...
In addition HTTPGET and FOLLOWLOCATION should also both be set to true.